# Discord.js can't register context menu

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been messing around with discord.js and wanted to add a context menu to my bot, for some reason whenever I start the bot I get this really weird error, I can't seem to solve it or find a solution online, here's the code:

```
const { ContextMenuCommandBuilder } = require(`@discordjs/builders`);

module.exports = {
    data: new ContextMenuCommandBuilder()
    .setName(`test`)
    .setType(`MESSAGE`),

    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.reply({
            content: `Successful.`,
            ephemeral: true
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the error:

```
C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1470
    return Result.err(new CombinedError(errors));
                      ^

CombinedError: Received one or more errors
    at UnionValidator.handle (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1470:23)     
    at UnionValidator.parse (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)       
    at validateType (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1462:17)
    at ContextMenuCommandBuilder.setType (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1484:5)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\NovaBot.js:65:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:367:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:189:14) {
  errors: [
    ExpectedValidationError: Expected values to be equals
        at LiteralValidator.handle (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:674:76)
        at LiteralValidator.run (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:102:23)   
        at UnionValidator.handle (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1465:32) 
        at UnionValidator.parse (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)   
        at validateType (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1462:17)
        at ContextMenuCommandBuilder.setType (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1484:5)
        at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\NovaBot.js:65:14)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
        at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
        at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:17) {
      validator: 's.literal(V)',
      given: 'MESSAGE',
      expected: 2
    },
    ExpectedValidationError: Expected values to be equals
        at LiteralValidator.handle (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:674:76)
        at LiteralValidator.run (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:102:23)   
        at UnionValidator.handle (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1465:32) 
        at UnionValidator.parse (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)   
        at validateType (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1462:17)
        at ContextMenuCommandBuilder.setType (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1484:5)
        at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\NovaBot.js:65:14)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
        at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
        at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\NovaBotAI\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:17) {
      validator: 's.literal(V)',
      given: 'MESSAGE',
      expected: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm at a loss, nothing I do seems to fix it, I tried changing the setType() value to a number and that got the code to start, but then it didn't register and I couldn't use it at all, but other than that I've got nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have fixed that already, but I have experienced the same issue today and solved it. I'm gonna post the solution, in case someone else needs it..

```
const { ContextMenuCommandBuilder } = require(`@discordjs/builders`);
const { ApplicationCommandType } = require('discord-api-types/v9');

module.exports = {
    data: new ContextMenuCommandBuilder()
    .setName(`test`)
    .setType(ApplicationCommandType.Message),

    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.reply({
            content: `Successful.`,
            ephemeral: true
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `module.exports` why don't you use the command directly like:

```js
const { client, ContextMenuInteraction } = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: "...",
    type: 'USER',
```

Comment: Incorrect. That will throw a syntax error, as `execute` should be an async method on the exported object.

Comment: Not gonna work, mine is programmed to push a SlashComnandBuilder() to JSON and then register it, for some reason it really doesn’t like the Context menu builder and has a massive error when I try and register it

Comment: Oh okay sorry, I have no idea about your error then